# R: maps package: Able to extend map boundary to custom longitude range?

Tags: r

I'm using the `map_data('world2')` data in ggplot2 with geom_map to plot some data, but I've run into a bit of an issue. I've divided up my regions into 3 longitude ranges (40E-140E, 140E-100W,100W-40E). As you can see, it doesn't fit neatly either into the (180W,180E) or (0,360) longitude ranges of the two world maps, so when I try to plot the data with a longitude axis that has a range encompassing the data, I get a blank portion of map on the right.

Is there a way to plot an extra slice of the map (i.e. 0->40E if using 'world2') adjacent to longitude 359? I tried manually adjusting the longitude values by doing the following:

```
m<-map_data('world2')
m$long<-ifelse((m$long>=0 & m$long<=40),m$long+360,m$long)

ggplot(data=longdata)+ 
coord_fixed(xlim=c(40,400),ylim=c(-90,90)) + 
geom_map(data= m, map = m, aes(map_id=region))
```

However, the resulting map is an ungodly mess, likely because the polygons are now all screwed up. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

AHA!

I just needed to modify m to the following:

```
m<-map_data('world2',wrap=c(40,400))
```